# Excel VBA Application.WorksheetFunction.Match Fails When Result is #N/A

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using Excel 2013 VBA.  I have the following data

```
       A                    B
1   John  Doe       John  Doe
2   Mary  Smith     Mary  Smith
3   Alice  Jones    Alice  Jones
4   Bob C Carter    Bob  Carter
5   David L Macy    David L Macy
6   June  Weaver    June  Weaver
```

I'm searching for exact matches of the entries in Column B with the range of entries in Column A using the partial code:

```
Dim lastAllScriptsRow As Integer                            
Dim compareOutlookRow As Integer                            
lastAllScriptsRow = 6                           
compareOutlookRow = 1                           
Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastAllScriptsRow, 1)).Select                          
… code …                            
If IsError(Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(compareOutlookRow, 2), Selection, 0)) Then
```

The search for the first three entries in Column B are successful.  When the search for the fourth entry, Bob  Carter, is conducted (note the entry of "Bob C Carter" in Column A preventing an exact match), I get a "Run-time error '1004':  Unable to get the Match property of the WorksheetFunction class."  I get the same error when I use Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA instead of IsError and when I use the positive approach using IsNumeric instead of IsError.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Application.Match` instead of `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match`.  The former will *return* an error that you can trap with `IsError` while the latter throws a run time error which is messier to deal with.

Note that Intellisense does not know that `Application.Match` exists.  It does though.

[This is a nice reference on the difference between the two.](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/09/24/the-worksheetfunction-method/)